# What is the "repository ID" discussed in the Travis-CI API?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

To get a list of builds using the TravisCI API described [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/#builds), it says that you need to put the repository ID in the request address.

I'm wondering, what is this ID, and where do I find it? Does it differ from the repository slug, which is `username/reponame?`

Answer (score 4):

The repository ID is the repo key which is shown in Travis CI API responses.

This can be either retrieve by:

```
$ curl -L http://api.travis-ci.org/repos/user_name/repo_name
```

or if you've `travis` command installed, try:

```
$ travis show -r user_name/repo_name
```

Here is corresponding code in Ruby:

```
require 'travis'
repos = Travis::Repository.find_all(owner_name: 'user_name')
repos.each do |repo|
  puts repo.slug
end
```

<sup>In above examples, change `user_name` and `repo_name` into the right values.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the TravisCI API, the repository ID is different from the slug.  It is a number assigned to the repository by Travis and unrelated to the Github repository ID.

For example: `curl https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/schwern/URI-Find` will return...

`{
 "id":527875,
 "slug":"schwern/URI-Find",
 "description":"Perl module to find URIs in arbitrary text",
 "public_key":"...",
 "last_build_id":29287626,
 "last_build_number":"10",
 "last_build_status":0,
 "last_build_result":0,
 "last_build_duration":28,
 "last_build_language":null,
 "last_build_started_at":"2014-07-07T03:43:28Z",
 "last_build_finished_at":"2014-07-07T03:44:03Z"
}`

You can use the `id` to access the repository as well. `curl https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/527875` will return the same thing.

As you can see with https://api.github.com/repos/schwern/URI-Find the Travis repository id differs from the Github repository id.

I assume the advantage of using the id vs the slug is the slug may change, repositories can be renamed and ownership transferred, but the id presumably will not.

Comment: This request returns me : `{ "file": "not found"}`

Comment: @BigDong Accessing them via a web browser is giving me XML rather than JSON now. They work with `curl`. Travis API v2 is being deprecated, so be sure to move to v3.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the repository id from the payload for the repository you're looking at, see http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/#repositories. The id in the payload for this endpoint is the id you can then use for the `/builds` endpoint.

That said, you can use either a slug or an id to fetch the builds for that repository, so these two yield the same result: https://api.travis-ci.org/builds?repository_id=82 and https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/sinatra/sinatra/builds