# Link badge to branch build history

Tags: travis-ci

When I'm looking for a badge with status for given branch I'm using `branch` parameter in URL. I'd like to do the same with the link to the latest build or build history of a given branch.

If this is not possible currently I'd be more than happy having such feature provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travis doesn't seem to currently implement this.

There is an open issue requesting such a feature though:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1996

Answer (score 2):

If you need URL, the only workaround is to point to:

```
https://travis-ci.org/{owner_name}/{repo_name}/branches
```

which would list all branch build history.

Otherwise access to branch build history this can be achieved via Travis CI API in JSON format (as discussed in [GH #1996](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1996#issuecomment-105707181)), so it's:

```
https://api.travis-ci.org//v3/repo/{repository.id}/branch/{branch.name}
```

To find your `repository.id`, see: [What is the “repository ID” discussed in the Travis-CI API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24617631/55075)